# What this small diameter drain tube coming out of my house wall?

Tags: water, leak

Tube is in the lower left of the photo. There is a small painted tube (similar to plant irrigation tubing) coming out of the wall about 12 inches off the ground that is dripping constant water.  There are normal condenser lines that are pvc that are not dripping water so I don’t think it’s coming from the furnace/condenser in the attic.

I’m in California and have had serious rain/ground saturation/flooding the past 2 weeks but not much in the past couple of days.  I’m inspecting the outside of the house because I found damp carpet inside the house on the same spot as this mystery tube.

Does anyone know what this line would be that is dripping water?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any way you can post some pictures?

Comment: do those 12 inches outside line up with the floor inside? If so, as @Ruskes suggests it could be a drain from, perhaps at the lowest point of the floor.

Comment: @P2000 the ground outside is roughly level with the floor inside

Comment: what is on the inside (other than wet carpet)? Are you able to cut a hole and inspect? I see two possible approaches: carefully cut hole(s) with perhaps a 4in hole saw form the inside, or attach a compressor nozzle and very (!) carefully back blow to see if you can identify where there's noise or bubbling. It could be an abandoned drain, that is now draining a water filled wall, so a search for rain leak would be warranted.

Comment: @P2000 I split the carpet and the pad was soaked in about a 3' semi circle from the wall.  The tack boards were soaked and moldy.  The slab had very little water.  I could feel moisture up and around/under the trim.  The reason I was asking about the tube is because it is the only source of water.  It was bent up behind another group of wires not letting it drain effectively assuming that was the intention.   ecnerwal had a possible reason for a drain in his response.  I guess the next step is to cut drywall to inspect for mold damage and trace the tube.

Comment: was it bent up as in "upward"? if so, that could indeed have been your water source, collecing a small portion of a lot of rain. If so, I would open the wall and remediate from the inside to remove/replace moist and moldy materials, and you probably can then determine the purpose of this pipe and potentially remove it if abandonned and close the hole. If you cut open from the inside you can take pictures and we can help you assess, fix and close up. Be very careful when cutting and try to only go as deep as the drywall (1/2in). Don't worry if you cut through vapour barrier.

Comment: It was bent upward but I don't know that it could gather as much water as it has been draining.  It's been dripping constantly for a few days.  I called in a buddy with experience to strategically remove the drywall.  I could do it but repairing it without it looking like crap is outside of my skillset.  He'll open it up this week to help eval the drywall/mold situation and help trace the mystery drain.

Comment: UPDATE -  I had the drywall cut and found that the small diameter tube was tapped into a 1 inch pvc pipe that went from an unused conduit box above it (with an unused pull string) down into the foundation.  I had a plumber try to trace it with a frequency type scanner but it just followed the main power line until about a 100' out and then we ran out of tape/frequency response.  Their best guess was that it was an unused conduit for outside future use that ran uphill that cracked or had condensation.  The builder knew there might be a problem and put in the drain.  No real good explanation.

Comment: Using the frequency scanner, we found a shallow spot that the plan is to dig it up and cap to avoid having any potential of water coming back into the house.... it was a head scratcher.  The builder knew there was going to be an issue but that was their fix.  Thanks for the ideas and help!

Comment: @Anthony: You might want to post that as an Answer to your own question, which folks could then comment upon if they have any further ideas about it. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Given what's above it, presumably the electrical installation is poorly flashed, and this is draining the bottom of the stud bay.

If so, presumably it does nothing when "it never rains in Southern California" but comes into play when "it pours, man it pours" - but without investigating further, that's speculation. If true, improving the waterproofing around  (or providing a roof-projection with the lowest part at least 78 inches above ground over) the electrical installation would eliminate the need for it.

Or it's connected to something under the house...

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It is a slab foundation so I wouldn't expect any type of sump pump or anything under the house for drainage but I also have never built a house so..... maybe?

There's an overhang from the house over that side but projection would definitely rule out water coming in from the side.  If I can't figure it out, that is something to add as a layer of protection.

Comment: @Anthony You're on the right track with cutting the wall open (carefully, given the electrical installation) to see what's really going on. Please update with pictures (and remember it's totally cool to answer your own question here.) I would not expect anything like this coming up from under a slab.

Comment: Thanks - I have an experienced friend coming out later this week to help open it up and evaluate the drywall and trace the drain for lack of any other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the update to what happened:

I had the drywall cut and found that the small diameter tube was tapped into a 1 inch pvc pipe that went from an unused conduit box above it (with an unused pull string) down into the foundation. I had a plumber try to trace it with a frequency type scanner but it just followed the main power line until about a 100' out and then we ran out of tape/frequency response. Their best guess was that it was an unused conduit for outside future use that ran uphill that cracked or had condensation. The builder knew there might be a problem and put in the drain. No real good explanation.  Using the frequency scanner, we found a shallow spot that the plan is to dig it up and cap to avoid having any potential of water coming back into the house.... it was a head scratcher. The builder knew there was going to be an issue but that was their fix. Thanks for the ideas and help!